# Cant find a persistence unit named my_bdd in deployment wildfly EJB EAR

Tags: web-services, maven, jpa, ejb, wildfly

I've a class that I would like to deploy on my wildly 10 server.

I created a persistence.xml file and followed a classical maven achétype. 
Here is my project structure :

```
├── pom.xml
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── dataRecovery
│   │   │       ├── ColisDao.java
│   │   │       ├── Colis.java
│   │   │       ├── FillDataBase.java
│   │   │       ├── GenerateDataBase.java
│   │   │       └── jaxws
│   │   │           ├── FillDataBase.java
│   │   │           ├── FillDataBaseResponse.java
│   │   │           └── IOExceptionBean.java
│   │   ├── resources
│   │   └── webapp
│   │       ├── META-INF
│   │       │   └── persistence.xml
│   │       ├── WEB-INF
│   │       │   ├── beans.xml
│   │       │   ├── cxf-beans.xml
│   │       │   ├── jboss-deployment-structure.xml
│   │       │   └── web.xml
│   │       └── wsdl
│   │           ├── filldatabase_schema1.xsd
│   │           └── filldatabase.wsdl
│   └── test
│       ├── java
│       └── resources
└── target
    ├── classes
    │   └── dataRecovery
    │       ├── Colis.class
    │       ├── ColisDao.class
    │       ├── FillDataBase.class
    │       ├── GenerateDataBase.class
    │       └── jaxws
    │           ├── FillDataBase.class
    │           ├── FillDataBaseResponse.class
    │           └── IOExceptionBean.class
    ├── m2e-wtp
    │   └── web-resources
    │       ├── META-INF
    │       │   ├── MANIFEST.MF
    │       │   └── maven
    │       │       └── com.recovery
    │       │           └── dataRecovery
    │       │               ├── pom.properties
    │       │               └── pom.xml
    │       ├── WEB-INF
    │       │   ├── beans.xml
    │       │   ├── cxf-beans.xml
    │       │   ├── jboss-deployment-structure.xml
    │       │   └── web.xml
    │       └── wsdl
    │           ├── filldatabase_schema1.xsd
    │           └── filldatabase.wsdl
    ├── maven-status
    │   └── maven-compiler-plugin
    │       └── compile
    │           └── default-compile
    │               ├── createdFiles.lst
    │               └── inputFiles.lst
    └── test-classes
```

The problem is when I want to deploy my FillDataBase.java class, I get following errors from my server logs :

```
WFLYJPA0033: Can't find a persistence unit named bdd_colis in deployment \"dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\""},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".INSTALL",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".beanmanager"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".beanmanager]",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".batch.environment is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".beanmanager]"
    ]
}
```

As other topics says, It could be due to a wrong `persistence.xml` file but I checked it and it seems to be good :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="bdd_colis" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/DataSource</jta-data-source>
        <class>dataRecovery.Colis</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

In addition, inside my ColisDao.java, which is my EJB object, I precised that the PersistenceContext would be named bdd_colis.

```
    @Stateless
    public class ColisDao {

        public static final String SELECT_ALL_COLIS = "select * from Colis;";

        @PersistenceContext(unitName="bdd_colis")
        private EntityManager em;
...
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

As per §8.2 of the JPA Specification:

> A persistence unit is defined by a persistence.xml file. The jar file or directory whose META-INF directory contains the persistence.xml file is termed the root of the persistence unit. In Java EE environments, the root of a persistence unit must be one of the following:
>   • an EJB-JAR file
>   • the WEB-INF/classes directory of a WAR file[87]
>   • a jar file in the WEB-INF/lib directory of a WAR file
>   • a jar file in the EAR library directory
>   • an application client jar file

Therefore, move your `META-INF/persistence.xml` file from the `src/main/webapp` directory to the `src/main/resources` directory.

Maven will then package this into the `WEB-INF/classes` directory of your WAR file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I'll try this evening and get back to you later :)